# Ruby on Rails cannot show paperclip avatar within the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, paperclip

I recently started to learn ruby on rails and I was able to successfully create an app and add users with devise, also add an avatar to the user with paperclip.

Now I'm having a problem on how to display the avatar throughout the app. The avatar only displays in `http:localhost:3000/users/...` (within the devise folders) for exemple, but if I try to create a new page, model, controller `http://localhost:3000/profile/` for exemple, using the the tag

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
```

the page will not load and will return this error

```
undefined method 'avatar?' for nil:NilClass
```

It's probably something really simple, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

My model `user.rb` looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates_uniqueness_of :username

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }

  attr_accessible :name, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :avatar
  attr_accessor :current_password
end
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def profile
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Definitely need more context here.  At a glance, it looks like the `@user` variable is not being defined in your profile controller.  Please post the code from your `Profile` model and controller.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the question with my model and controller. Hope this help.

Comment: You first need to find where the method `avatar?` is being called (note this is different from the method `avatar` that you have shown in the sample `<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On routes.rb, you should have something like this:

```
match "profile" => "user#profile"
```

On your `UserController`, you should have something like this:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def profile
    @user = current_user
  end
end
```

And then you'll be able to use  `@user.avatar.url`. Also, pay attention that if you don't have a logged in user, current_user will be `nil`, and then you will have the error you described, so please add something like this on your controller:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def profile
    @user = current_user
  end
end
```

And then, when a unauthenticated account tries to access `/profile`, it'll be redirected to the login form.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I had '@user = User.find(current_user.username)' initially but I was getting some weird error. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

I am still new to Rails so correct me if I am wrong but I think this might work for you.

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def profile
    @user = User.find(current_user.username)
  end
end
```

Comment: What is your primary key in this case?

Comment: I have used '@user = current_user' and it worked. Thanks anyways! :)